# Xcode: Zombies not discovered in Instruments

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, memory-leaks, nszombie

When I enable Zombie Objects in the "Run" scheme the App works fine on the iPad, if I uncheck this option it crashes. In the search of these zombies I ran the "Profile" together with the "Zombies" template in Instruments. It doesn't crash in the Simulation mode and therefore doesn't give a message. What other ways are there to find zombies?

Comment: If it crashes when disabling the detection of zombies, something may be causing memory corruption. You may want to start by trying to find that before tracking the zombies.

Answer (score 1):

[There's a bug in iOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132325/xcode-instrument-allocations-instrument-not-finding-zombies/12133275#12133275) preventing deallocation of instance variables under ARC and `NSZombieEnabled`. This explains the described changing of behavior with or without zombies.

Solution: Switch to iOS 6 under Mountain Lion.

Comment: Thanks Nikolai, but even after migrating to Mountain Lion and deploying the target to iOS 6, I still don't get a Zombie Message in Instruments.